# Every neighborhood of identity in a topological group contains the product of a symmetric neighborhood of identity.

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a topological group and $U$ be a neighborhood of $1$.  Then there exists a symmetric neighborhood of $1$, $V^{-1} = V$, such that $V\cdot V \subset U$.  Having a hard time proving this.  $V^{-1} = \{v^{-1}: v \in V\}$.  I know that an open set times any set is also open.  And a hint is that $VV^{-1}$ is symmetric and an open neighborhood of $1$ when $V$ is an open neighborhood of $1$ contained in $U$, but showing $VV^{-1}$ or an expression involving it is a subset of $U$ or $V$ requires something else.

Comment: By definition of a topological group, the multiplication $\mu \colon G\times G \to G$ is continuous. In particular, it is continuous at $(e,e)$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use that the multiplication is continuous and $1\cdot1=1$. Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $1$. By continuity there are neighborhoods $A,B\ni1$ such that $AB\subseteq U$. Let $W=A\cap B$ and then $V:=W\cap W^{-1}$ is a symmetric neighborhood of $1$ such that $VV\subseteq U$.

Comment: What definition of continuity are you using?

Comment: If $V$ is a neighborhood of $f(x)$, then there is a nbh $U$ of $x$ with $f[U]\subseteq V$.

Comment: You beat me to the answer!

Comment: I don't like your variable replacements though, just use another letter!

Comment: @EnjoysMath: I know one should avoid such variable replacements, even if the original $V$ is not used any more. I've changed it :-)

Comment: How do we know that we can take the neighbourhood of 1 as AB? How do we know it can be in of the form AB?

Comment: @Natasha: We take two neighborhoods $A$ and $B$ of $1$, such that the image of $A\times B$ under the multiplication map, i.e. the set $AB$, is a subset of $U$.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks so much!

Answer (score 5):

Take the continuous function $m:G\times G\to G$ where $(x,y)\mapsto xy$. Then $m^{-1}(U)$ is open and maps to $U$. We can then take a neighborhood of $1$, let's say $V$, such that $V\times V\subseteq m^{-1}(U)$ (since $m^{-1}(U)$ is open using the product topology). By replacing $V$ with $V\cap V^{-1}$, we can assume that $V$ is symmetric. Therefore $m(V,V)=VV\subseteq U$ and $V$ is symmetric.

Comment: If we replace $V$ by $VV^{-1}$, we would need that $VV^{-1}VV^{-1}$ is a subset of $U$.