# A property of compact group

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

$G$ is a compact group with identity $e$. Prove: $$\forall x\in G,   e\in \overline{(x^n)}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$$

The overline indicates the closure of this sequence. I'm confused because there is no distance or norm defined in the question, I don't know what to do with the condition "compact". Could someone help me?

Thanks~

Comment: Why do you think you need distance, norm or whatever for "closed", "closure", "compact" and etc.? These are notions from general topology, something you must know *before* studying topological groups...

Comment: @DonAntonio It's indeed an exercise in my general topology course. I know the notations... but I don't know anything about topological groups. I'm wondering what's special for a group...

Comment: But then you know what is "closure, compact", etc., right? Why then would you wonder about "distance or norm" ?

Comment: For instance, in the course we defined "close" in a metric space... One more thing, I just cannot imagine how these things work in a "group" with only operation product...

Comment: Forget for a moment the group thing: $\;G\;$ is a *topological* space, so it makes sense to talk about its subsets, sequences, closures and etc. Now, in a topological space $\;X\;$, if we have subset $\;A\subset X\;$ (say with the inherited topology), what does it mean that $\;x\in\overline A\;$ ? Well, this is what you have here! You may probably better write it $\;e\in\overline {\{x_n\}}\;$ , and put $\;A=\{x_n\}\;$ , but it's the same.

Comment: @DonAntonio kinda understand... I retry this problem, thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all if $x$ is of finite order then the statement is trivial since $e=x^n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So assume that $x$ is of infinite order.

From the general topology we know that

$$z\in\overline{A}$$

if and only if for any open neighbourhood $U$ of $z$ we have $U\cap A\neq\emptyset$.

So lets take any open neighbourhood $U$ of $e$. Then there exists a [symmetric, almost product-closed sub-neighbourhood](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467832/every-neighborhood-of-identity-in-a-topological-group-contains-the-product-of-a) $V$ of $U$, i.e.
$$V\mbox{ is open}$$
$$e\in V$$
$$V\subseteq U$$
$$V^{-1}=V$$
$$VV\subseteq U.$$

The last property is what I call "almost product-closed" (it's not a standard nomenclature, just a name I came up with just now). So $V$ is pretty close to being a subgroup, except that $VV$ can actually be a bit bigger then $V$. We will use these properties later.

Now since $G$ is a topological group, then $\{gV\}_{g\in G}$ is an open cover of $G$. Furthermore since $G$ is compact then this cover has a finite subcover

$$\{g_1V,\ldots,g_mV\}$$

Now since $x$ is of infinite order, then [the pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) implies that there are $i>j$ such that $x^i,x^j\in g_kV$ for some $k$. So write

$$x^i=g_ka$$
$$x^j=g_kb$$

for some $a,b\in V$. Then $x^{-j}=b^{-1}g_k^{-1}$ and so

$$x^{i-j}=x^{-j}x^i=b^{-1}g_k^{-1}g_ka=b^{-1}a$$

In particular $x^{i-j}\in V^{-1}V$ and since $V$ is symmetric and almost product-closed, then $x^{i-j}\in U$. Finally $i>j$ implies that $x^{i-j}\in\{x^n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and thus we've shown that

$$U\cap \{x^n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\neq\emptyset$$

which completes the proof. $\Box$