# Is there a name for this?

Tags: terminology, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a topological group.

Let $U$ be an open neighborhood of the identity in $G$. It is well known there exists another open neighborhood of the identity $V$ in $G$ such that $V\cdot V\subseteq U$.

Is there a name for $V$?

Comment: I have seen this in [Raghunathan](http://www.springer.com/de/book/9783642864285). How does he call this? Not Zassenhaus neighbourhood, this was something different ...May be it has no special name. See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467832/every-neighborhood-of-identity-in-a-topological-group-contains-the-product-of-a).

Answer (score 0):

No.

At least, I've never heard of a name for this concept, and I am fairly certain there is no standard name for it.

This is a very old question, but I decided to give my 2 cents for what it's worth anyway.