# the closure of a set in a topological group

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

This question is a exercise from Folland's Real analysis (chapter 11, question 1).

If $G$ is a topological group and $E\subset G$, then the closure $\bar{E}=\cap\{EV: V$ is a neighborhood of $ e\}$.

Any help would be apreciated!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I tried use the characterization of $\bar{E}=\{x \in G: V\cap E\neq \empty, \forall V$  neighborhood of $x \}$ but didn't go anywhere

Comment: What is the intersection over? I understand it is Folland's custom to abbreviate notation but in this case it is not clear to me what the right-hand side of the expression is supposed to mean.

Comment: @Math1000 over all neighborhoods of $e$.

Comment: Let $x\in\overline{E}$. Then, there is a net $x_i\in E$, for $i\in D$ and $D$ directed, such that $x_i\to x$. Let $V$ be any neighborhood of $e$. Since $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is continuous, then $x_i^{-1}\to x^{-1}$. Since $(x,y)\mapsto xy$ is also continuous it follows that $x_i^{-1}x\to e$. Therefore, there is $i_0\in I$ such that for all $i>i_0$ we have $x_i^{-1}x\in V$. Therefore, $x=x_ix_i^{-1}x\in EV$. This proves that $\overline{E}\subset \bigcap_{V}EV$ for $V$ open neighborhoods of $e$.

Comment: Then what is $e$? Some point of $E$?

Comment: @conditionalMethod Thanks!! A very elegant approach!

Comment: @Math1000 $e$ is the identity element of the (topological) group

Comment: Oh, that should have been obvious. I have been reading Dummit & Foote where they use $1$ for the identity element. My bad.

Comment: Conversely. Assume that $x\in \bigcap_VEV$. Then, for each open $V\ni e$ there are $x_V\in E$ and $u_V\in V$ such that $x=x_Vu_V$. Let $I$ be the directed set of all open neighborhoods of $e$ ordered by inclusion. Then $I$ is directed, and $V\mapsto u_V$ is a net. This net converges to $e$ by construction. By continuity of $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ we have that $u_V^{-1}$ also converges to $e^{-1}=e$. Therefore, by continuity of $(x,y)\mapsto xy$, we have that $x_V=xu_V^{-1}$ converges to $xe=x$. Hence $x\in\overline{E}$.

Comment: The fact that $u_V\to e$ consists in checking the definition. For all open $U\ni e$, there is an element of $I$ (that element is $U$ itself) such that if $V\in I$ with $V>U$ (which by our definition of order means $V\subset U$), then $x_V\in U$. This is true because $x_V\in V\subset U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $G$ is Hausdorff and second countable (to avoid nets). Let $F(E)=\cap \{VE$, $V$ is a neighborhood of the identity$\}$. Firstly, we remark that $F$ is closed. Suppose that $x$ is not in $F(E)$, there exists a neighborhood $V$ such that $x$ is not in $EV$. There exists an open subset $U$ such that $U=U^{-1}$ and $UU^{-1}\subset V$, see the reference. $x$ is also not in $EU$, as $EU \subseteq EV$.

We claim that $EU\cap xU=\emptyset$: if not, let $y=eu=xu', u,u'\in U, e\in E$, we have $x=eu{u'}^{-1}$, which implies that $x\in EU$ since $UU^{-1}\subset V$. This implies that the complement of $F$ is open and $F(E)$ is closed.

Let $L$ be any closed subset, we claim that $F(L)=L$. Let $x\in F(L)$, and $U_n$ a sequence of neighborhoods of $e$ such that $\cap_nU_n=\{e\}$. $x=u_nf_n, u_n\in U_n, f_n\in F$. This implies that $f_n=xu_n^{-1}$ and converges towards $x$, we deduce that $x\in F$.

Let $E$ be any subset,  and $L$ a closed subset which contains $E$, for every neighborhood $V$ of the identity, $EV\subset LV$ implies that $F(E)\subset F(L)=L$, this implies that $F(E)$ is closed subset contained in every closed subset which conatains $E$ so it is the adherence of $E$.

[Every neighborhood of identity in a topological group contains the product of a symmetric neighborhood of identity.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467832/every-neighborhood-of-identity-in-a-topological-group-contains-the-product-of-a)